# Beamer slides moving in odd way

Tags: beamer, pdftex

When I create a PDF using the MME below, the slides behave oddly. When each line is revealed, the whole slide shifts, making the upper part invisible. I'm not sure what is going on. I don't think the slides are too crowded, as it happens even on some later slides that are much emptier.

I get no warnings or errors in the log.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: I found that this problem only exists when I compile the slides and then look at the presentation. If I open the PDF from Windows Explorer, things are fine.

```
\documentclass {beamer} {
  \mode<presentation> {
  %\usetheme{Goettingen}
  % or ...

  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  % or whatever (possibly just delete it)
  \usecolortheme{albatross}
  \usecolortheme{sidebartab}
  \useoutertheme{split}
}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% or whatever

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
% or whatever

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Or whatever. Note that the encoding and the font should match. If T1
% does not look nice, try deleting the line with the fontenc.

\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg = white, bg = white}
\setbeamercolor{description item}{fg = red, bg = blue}

\AtBeginSection {
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}



\title[] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{Slowly Diverging Series }


\author{Peter L. Flom }
% - Use the \inst{?} command only if the authors have different
%   affiliation.

\institute[] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{}

\date[May 2022] % (optional)
{Math for Math's Sake}

\subject{Talks}
% This is only inserted into the PDF information catalog. Can be left
% out.



% If you wish to uncover everything in a step-wise fashion, uncomment
% the following command:

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[pausesections]
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Introduction}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item Infinite series can either diverge, converge, or be indeterminate. Many divergent series diverge very quickly, or at a constant rate.
  \item Some series diverge slowly. The most famous of these is surely the harmonic series:
     $ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + \dots$
  \item After 1000 terms, it is only about 7.85.
  \item But are there series that diverge even more slowly?
  \item Indeed there are!
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Proofs of divergence}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The elementary proof}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item 1 is equal to 1
  \item 1/2 is equal to 1/2
  \item 1/3 + 1/4 is greater than 1/2, because $1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2 \text{ and } 1/3 > 1/4$
  \item 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7 + 1/8 is greater than 1/2, because $1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 = 1/2$ and the other fractions are all greater than 1/8.
  \item and so on. We just need twice as many terms in each successive sum. But we have an infinite number of terms, to that is not a problem.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, I can't confirm your findings. Your MWE works fine. Which version of ˙beamer` you use?

Comment: According to my log, it is 3.59

Comment: Upgrade it. Recent version is 3.66.

Comment: I am not sure how.  It usually upgrades automatically.